# reworking maploading from sdcard to assets in android

Tags: android, mapsforge

I'm trying to load from an existing file from the asset folder, rather than SD card as my code below does:

```
MapDataStore mapDataStore = new MapFile(
    new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "berlin.map"));
```

I am unsure how to do this in Android and am looking for help.

Comment: org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapFile is from mapsforge lib not from osmdroid-lib. I fixed the question tags. I have looked into [MapFile.java](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/mapsforge-map-reader/src/main/java/org/mapsforge/map/reader/MapFile.java) and i found no stream api that is neccessary for asset access. Maybe somebody from mapsforge can help you. the osmdroid-mapsforge-integration currently does not support mapsforge maps in assets. If you find out how to do it please add it to this ticket so that we can add it to osmdroid-mapsforge-integration, too

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can't access a .map file in the assets folder. You have to copy it from there to the SD card.

```
private void provideMapData() {
    String sourceFile = res.getString(R.array.mapsource);
    String destinationFile = res.getString(R.array.mapdestination);
    String pathPrefix = activity.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/";

    File directory = new File(pathPrefix);
    if (directory.exists() | directory.mkdirs()) {
        AssetManager assetManager = activity.getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream;
        OutputStream outputStream;
        File file = new File(pathPrefix + destinationFile);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                inputStream = assetManager.open(sourceFile);
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int read;
                while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException iOE) {
                Log.e("Error: ", "provideMapData()");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I load the MapDataStore like this:

```
MapDataStore mapDataStore = new MapFile(new File(activity.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + destinationFile));
```

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html#jd-content), you should put this into your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

It will save you from explicitly asking the user to grant WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.